# real positive roots for higher characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, roots

It is well known that cubic characteristic polynomials with positive discriminate have real positive roots. I want to know that under what assumptions we have real roots for higher characteristic polynomials?
positive discriminate is necessarily not enough for the higher-dimensional case.